# How to automatically add new files in spark notebook from adls gen 2

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Can we automatically load new files added in adls gen2 into spark pool notebook? I am hard coding the parquet file name in my spark scala notebook for loading the file. I want all the new files which are added to be automatically loaded into my notebook.

Comment: Use a wildcard in the path to a directory?

Comment: what about files which are already processed how can I skip them

Comment: The usual approach in a data lake is to store files in dated directories and keep a watermark, ie what dates you have processed.

Comment: Okay but that means I need to change the directory everytime I run my spark pool code? I actually wanted to just run the spark pool in one go and perform the loading of new files

Comment: I use ADF pipeline to call parametrised notebook.

Comment: I am new to synapse can you please elaborate or share any code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement using storage event triggers and parameterized notebooks. Parameterized notebooks are only regular notebooks with parameters passed from the pipeline.

A storage event trigger is used to start the execution of pipeline if a file is uploaded, copied or deleted from a specific storage account. This type of trigger starts executing the pipeline for each of the uploaded file(s).

Implement the following steps to achieve this:

- Create a notebook and create a `filename` parameter and toggle the cell to `parameter cell` as shown in the image (mssparkutils.notebook.exit({filename}) is just for my reference). Write the rest of your code using this `filename` parameter whose value will be in the format `<filename>.<extension>`.

[image]

- Now create a pipeline, using synapse `Notebook` activity. Create a parameter for pipeline called `triggeringFile`. Go to notebook activity and specify your notebook to which you want to load the file.

[image]

- Create a new parameter for notebook activity called filename with value as `@pipeline().parameters.triggeringFile` referring to the value of the pipeline parameter `triggeringFile` which we will pass to this notebook.

[image]

- Now create a trigger for this pipeline by clicking `Trigger -> New/Edit`. Choose to create a new trigger and specify fields as specified below (The value of blob path begins with is just the path to your ADLS gen2 folder, you can leave it empty if the files are uploaded directly to container and **blob path ends with is '.parquet' as you are working with parquet**).

[image]

- When you click continue, you can see trigger parameter values triggeringFile. Specify its value as `@trigger().outputs.body.fileName` Which gives the filename of the file that triggered the pipeline.

[image]

- Publish the pipeline and trigger. When you upload any number of files to this ADLS gen2 storage, each of those files will trigger the pipeline. I have uploaded a file named `sample.csv` and you can see that the pipeline execution succeeds, and when you monitor the pipeline you can see that filename parameter is successfully passed to the notebook where it can be processed further.

[image]

Comment: hi @Saideep one query here the filename variable you are processing in the notebook are we able to get the filename also, as in my case i am reading filename in my dataframe for processing

Comment: Can you give more clarity about what you are trying to do?

Comment: hi @Saideep, so here i am also fetching the file from adls with parameterization , everytime only one file is there in adls and once that file is processed we are deleting that file from folder and fetching new file

Comment: my question here is as you have mentioned in your answer filename, as while doing transformtions i am also using file name and putting filename in one of my dataframe columns so the query is by using your method can we get filename also in the notebook

Comment: If you are using synapse notebooks, then the above process will give you the filename for that particular file which is triggered by storage event trigger. The name will be retrieved via the parameter created in parameter cell (1st image) which can be used as you like. Try raising a new question for any issues that you might be facing.